# Calling model inside a middleware laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to call a model `Readdb` inside a middleware. but I am getting error :

> Class 'app\Models\Readdb' not found

My middlware code is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Readdb;

class Adminlogin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!$request->session()->has('userid')) {
            $db = new Readdb();
            return response()->view('admin.auth.login');
        } else {
            return response()->view('admin.dash');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**Readdb File:**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Readdb extends Model {

    public function get_setting($name) {
        $data = DB::table('setting')->select('value')->where('name', '=', $name)->get();
        return $data->value;
    }

}
```

path to readdb is: `/var/www/html/ecommerce/app/Models/Readdb.php`

Comment: there is something weird between "app/Models..." and "App/Models"

Comment: Can you share the Readdb file too please, including the path to its location. Your composer.json might be helpful too, to see how include paths are set up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Readdb` exists in the namespace `App`, not `App\Models`, so either do this in the middleware:

```
use App\Readdb;
```

Or, if your `composer.json` says to look for `App\Models` in the `app/Models` dir, update the namespace on `Readdb`:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Comment: I did **use App\Readdb;** at middleware but now getting error : Class 'App\Readdb' not found

Comment: @HarenSarma try the second solution then.

Comment: yes second solution work.. but why not the first one ! what I am missing ?

Comment: It's because it broke PSR-4 standards so it stopped being autoloaded.

Comment: @HarenSarma look in your `composer.json`, there's a directive that says namespace `App\Models` should be loaded from the folder `app/Models`. I offered 2 possible solutions since I didn't have enough information from what you posted to know for sure which way to fix it.

Comment: @mopo922 this is in my composer.json

"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },

Comment: @HarenSarma So that will trickle down to anything inside `app`, as long as the directory structure matches the namespace.